# How to validate Rails Model attribute uniqueness over a virtual attribute scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How can I validate uniqueness of an attribute with a custom or virtual scope?  I thought of using a virtual attribute, but it keeps trying to query audit_year in the database.  I would rather not create another database column just for the purpose of this uniqueness constraint.

Each location can only have one audit scheduled per year, so I need to extract the year from the scheduled attribute and validate uniqueness over that scope.

```
class Audit
    attr_accessible :location_name, :scheduled_date, :completion_date ...

    validates :location_name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => { :scope => :audit_year }

    ...

    def audit_year
        scheduled_date.year
    end

end
```

I may not even be on the correct path with my virtual attribute attempts. What would be the "right" way to do this in rails?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but I figured I'd pitch in. I'm doing this from memory so you may need to screw with this a bit.

My first thought is in your audit_year method, you could query the database for all years.  Something like:

```
def audit_year
  !self.class.select('selected_date').map{ |a| a.selected_date.year }.include?(selected_date.year)
  # or using Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3:
  # !self.class.pluck('created_at').map(&:year).include?(selected_date.year)
end
```

My assumption of the unique method is if it returns false, it will fail validation.  This code selects just that one column from your class (I used self.class instead of Audit so it's more reusable), then maps out the years to an array.  If it's included (true), return the opposite (!).  You could probably optimize the query with uniq, but it depends on how large the table is whether it's necessary or not.

The other option would be to roll your own validator for the attribute, which really wouldn't be that difficult.  The only difference is you'd add a line that conditionally checks for `selected_date.present?` in addition to the above.  A great resource is the Rails Guides for callbacks and errors if you don't know how: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

Hope that helps.